# Travel to China as a Chinese national

Tags: china, hong-kong

My wife is a Chinese national residing in Belgium.
We would like to do the following itinerary:

Belgium --> Hong Kong (<7 days) --> Mainland China (e.g. Chengdu) --> Belgium

I assume my wife does not need a permit to go to Hong Kong. 
I assume she can return to Belgium from mainland China (no need to go back from Hong Kong)?

Can anyone confirm my assumptions ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. She does not need a visa to transit Hong Kong for less than 7 days between a foreign country and Mainland China.